# Place 3 box in a single row

Tags: php, html, css

I am fetching data images from database and wish to place maximum 3 images in a single row and these images also have hover effect on them which is working fine

problem that i am facing is that if i am using this code to display static images then it is working fine but if i fetch the data from database then it is not displaying properly. i want to display images in this form

```
1st_image  2nd_image  3rd_image   
4th_image  5th_image  6th_image  
7th_image .. and so on
```

but i am getting images in this form

```
1st_image  
2nd_image  
3rd_image   
4th_image  
5th_image  
6th_image
```

The code that i have is

code of my front page is

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $catname=$row["catname"];
                $catdesc=$row["catdesc"];
                $catpic=$row["catpic"];
                $id=$row["id"];

?>
                <div id="effect-2" class="effects clearfix">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="<? echo $catpic; ?>" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a href="#" class="">content</a>
                                <a class="close-overlay hidden">x</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?}
    }?>
```

code on css page is

```
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #32c896;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #238b68;
}
nav ul li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #238b68;
}


.effects {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.effects .img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.effects .img:nth-child(n) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.effects .img:first-child {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.effects .img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.effects .img img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

a.close-overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.close-overlay.hidden {
  display: none;
}

a.expand {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 5px #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}


#effect-2 .overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
#effect-2 .overlay a.expand {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
}
#effect-2 .img.hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

can anyone tell me how to do so

Comment: You should have unique ids on this line-> `<div id="effect-2" class="effects clearfix">`

Comment: you could just do something like `float:left;width:33%`

Answer (score 0):

You should use unique ids in your html. I recommend to always use classes instead of id. You can do something like this in your `CSS`

```
div[id^="tocolor-"] {
    /* some css rules */
}
div[id^="tocolor-"] .overlay {
    /* some css rules */
}
```

And in your html you can add an `id` using database table `id` like this

```
<div id="effect-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="effects clearfix">
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use bootstrap and use `col-xs-4` class...which will make sure you always have 3 columns

```
<div id="effect-2" class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="<? echo $catpic; ?>" alt="">
        <div class="overlay"> <a href="#" class="">content</a>
 <a class="close-overlay hidden">x</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP didnt mention anything about bootstrap.